# Submit Button in django bootstrap form doesn't work

Tags: django

I'm begginer in making django projects.

I'm creating easy app which plots earthquakes positions on map with data from api.
One of features of my app is the possibility to paste range of dates to my api query.

I made the form which includes the datepicker and the code in views that i suppose should handle it.

I have problem because my submit button that should grab data from  datepicker doesn't work.
Or may be i did  something wrong  in my views and  it cannot take data from post method to variable `datebeg` and `dateend`
Any idea?

views.py

```
def graph(request):

#=========data=========================================================================
    datebeg='2021-03-19'
    dateend='2021-03-20'
    if request.method == 'post':
        datebeg=request.POST['datebeg']
        dateend = request.POST.get("dateend")

        if datebeg=='':
            datebeg='2021-03-21'
        if dateend=='':
            dateend='2021-03-21'
```

graph.html

```
<body>
<div class="container my-container">
    <form  action="{% url 'graph' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class= "row my-row">
              <div class="col-4 my-col">


                          Trzęsienia ziemi z zakresu dat:

              </div>
              <div class="col-4 my-col">

                  od:
                  <input type="date" placeholder="0" name="datebeg" size="1" />

              </div>
              <div class="col-4 my-col">
                  do:
                       <input type="date" placeholder="0" name="dateend" size="1" />
              </div>


          <a class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" href="{% url 'graph'%}" >Pokaż na mapie</a>
          </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

graph/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.graph,name='graph'),
]
```

Comment: repace `<a ...>`, with `<button ...>`.

Comment: I have tried. It seems not to be case. It still doesn't work

Comment: I replace 'post' witch 'POST' and I changed  'dateend = request.POST.get("dateend")'  for  dateend = request.POST[dateend] and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Yours if condition is invalid
You need to use

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

In Django 3>, best practice is to use Class Based Views, you don't need to add that condition in case of:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

class MyView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse('result')
```

You can read more about it there [Django-Class-Based-Views-Intro](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/)